# Showing $\| Mx \|^2 = x^TM^TMx$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

So, I am trying to prove $$\|Mx\|^2 =x^TM^TMx,$$ however I am running into some difficulties.

Here, $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I know that when you take the transpose you get a $1 \times n$ matrix for $x^T$ and an $n \times m$ matrix for $M^T$. So, when you multiply those you get a $1 \times m$ matrix, then again if you do that times $M$ you get a $1 \times n$ matrix, and then finally a $1 \times 1$ matrix, but I am a bit unsure on how to actually go about the proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: $x^TM^TMx = (Mx)^T(Mx)$. Now think how the standard dot product is defined.

Comment: It would be $((M_1 x_1)^2 + (M_2 x_2)^2 + ...... + (M_n x_n)^2)$, ah, so simple yet frustrating if you try and treat it as individual elements. Thank you!

Comment: One last thing: formally, the equality is not correct since $\|Mx\|^2$ is a field element and $x^TM^TMx$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix, meaning a mapping $\{1\} \times \{1\} \rightarrow K$. Formally correct would be $\|Mx\|^2 = (x^TM^TMx)_{1,1}$

Comment: What do you mean by field element exactly? The notation at the end is new to me.

Comment: The entries of matrices are usually elements of some [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29) (for example, the real numbers or the complex numbers). If $A$ is a matrix, then $A_{i,j}$ denotes the entry in line $i$, column $j$.

Comment: In your case, you would have $\|Mx\|^2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x^TM^TMx \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 1}$, which formally are not the same sets.

Comment: Informally, nobody makes a distinction between $1\times1$ matrices and numbers.